# SharePoint 2010 Document List

Tags: 2010, document-library, document

Good morning.

I have a set of requirements for some simple document storage and I am investigating the possibility of using an existing SharePoint 2010 system.

We need:

- A location where multiple documents will be submitted on a weekly
  basis.
- All previous weeks documents must be maintained for traceability.
- An alert/notification/email should be generated at the end of each
  week which indicates any documents which have not been submitted.
- It should be possible to add comments to each of the submitted
  documents.

My main question is if this would be possible within SharePoint 2010 without the use of customised webparts?  If so how would I approach implementing this and what should I be reading up on?

Any suggestions or pointers to relevant information or starting advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

•A location where multiple documents will be submitted on a weekly basis.
**-> Use a Document Library**

•All previous weeks documents must be maintained for traceability.
•An alert/notification/email should be generated at the end of each week which indicates any documents which have not been submitted.
**-> You can create a job for this**

•It should be possible to add comments to each of the submitted documents.
**-> Add Comment column to the List or Create a new Content Type based on Document Content Type and add the Comment column to the created CT. finaly associate the content type to your list.**

Comment: "An alert/notification/email should be generated at the end of each week which indicates any documents which have not been submitted." --> The easiest solution would be to configure alerts on the library. Then you get an e-mail "report" about _submitted_ documents. Depending on the amount of documents, this may be a feasible (cheap) solution